Getting the private IP of the phone on my hotspot when it's connected to data
I want to use scrcpy remotely if I'm on mobile data, so I decided to turn on my mobile hotspot, connect to WiFi, and connect my laptop to it. Of course, that works. But if I disconnect from WiFi and connect to mobile data, there is no way for me to access my phone  when I'm on the hotspot.
Surely the phone would give itself a private IP on the hotspot, right? If so, how do I find it?

Normally the phone hotspot IP is identical to the gateway IP your laptop gets via DHCP. But I do remember that on Hotspot interface services like adb are not available.

this may help

Thanks, I didn't see that post but it seems like this is a duplicate of that. Will try this soon!
